# Control to parent screen after modal closed

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot app with thymeleaf. On my landing page I have multiple modals. On click of save I am doing ajax call and closing the modal through:

document.getElementById("saveParcelButton").setAttribute("data-dismiss","modal");

Every modal id is unique. After the successful call the control doesn't go back to parent screen and the parent screen remain frozen. It happens sometimes and not the other times. It's very unpredictable. I don't see any issues in the console and compared the data when it is working and when it is not and it looks same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this problem.Looks like modal-backdrop class is being added whenever the screen freeze and stays there. Added the properties
 data-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false" to the opening link and it worked perfect.